# Makefile not building objects how I'm telling it to

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my project directory file tree:

```
.
├── entity.cpp
├── entity.hpp
├── entitytypes.hpp
├── main.cpp
├── Makefile
├── player.cpp
└── player.hpp
```

`Makefile`'s contents is this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -pg
LDFLAGS=-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
EXE=gametest

all: $(EXE)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(EXE): main.o entity.o player.o
    g++ $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

And very oddly, this is the output when I type `make`:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o entity.o entity.cpp
g++    -c -o player.o player.cpp
g++ main.o entity.o player.o -o gametest -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

So as you can see, the last line of the output corresponds to the `$(EXE)` section of the Makefile. It's linking the program with the correct flags, etc. My problem is that when each individual object file is build, it's not at all taking into account my `%.o: %.c` rule. This is clear since when it builds the objects, there is a long gap between `g++` and `-c`, which I didn't write. Also, it's missing out my $(CFLAGS). Even weirder, when I comment out the `%.o: %.c` section, the Makefile does the *exact* same thing.

It seems to me like it's using some kind of default build command, and just ignoring mine.

I've looked at Makefiles I've written in the past which as far as I can tell use the exact same macros in the same way, so I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: Change `%.o: %.c` to `%.o: %.cpp` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your files as *.cpp while your rules said *.c, that's why.

Comment: You and @Galik are both right, and I'm kicking myself for not noticing that. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a half converted Makefile for `C`. It uses the wrong variables and looks for `C` files rather than `C++`. Try this (untested):

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -pg
LDFLAGS := -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
EXE := gametest

all: $(EXE)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< 

$(EXE): main.o entity.o player.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

`C++` uses `CXX` whereas `C` uses `CC`, same with `CXXFLAGS`.

**Note:** Remember the indentations are `TAB`s not spaces!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule uses **`CXX`** (not `CC`) to specify the compiler, and **`CXXFLAGS`** (not `CFLAGS`) for the flags.  So re-write your Makefile to set those variables, and you don't need to specify the pattern rule yourself:

```make
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pg
LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

gametest: main.o entity.o player.o
gametest: LINK.o = LINK.cc
```